Has any US president ever endorsed Trump for US presidency?
Currently, former/current US presidents Bill Clinton, Barack Obama, and Joe Biden are expressing support for US presidential candidate Kamala Harris.   This makes me wonder:
Question: Has any US president ever endorsed Trump for US presidency?
Obviously, Donald Trump is a former president and endorses Donald Trump, but other than that (everyone endorses themselves).
I did a bit of Googling, and didn't find a single example.  I found George W. Bush criticizing Trump's age (along with Biden's).  Jimmy Carter once called Trump an "illegitimate president".  But of course, people change their minds, and it's been quite a while now since we first started talking about Trump being US president.

Just as a note, 2016, 2020, and 2024 were not the only elections in which Donald Trump ran for President of the United States. He also ran in the Reform Party in 2000 and openly considered running a few others times from 1988 all the way up through 2012. I'm not aware of any endorsements from a sitting or former President during any of those runs, though. In stark contrast to his 2016 through present runs, he was pretty much a moderate back then. He was a Democrat for most of his life.

The simple answer is "No". A lot of that has to do with the current makeup of living ex-presidents. That list includes

Jimmy Carter (1976), who is a Democrat
George H.W. Bush (1988), who openly voted for Clinton in 2016. His son, Jeb Bush, ran against Trump in the primary. He is now deceased.
Bill Clinton (1992), a Democrat who is married to Hillary Clinton (ran against Trump in 2016)
George W. Bush (2000), a Republican who doesn't seem to like Trump any more than his father did. He also declined to endorse him in 2020
Barack Obama (2008), who is a Democrat

So why is George W. Bush silent in 2024? A lot of it has to do with his personal beliefs about the role ex-presidents play

While people often call on Bush to speak out against Trump and the Republican Party he has remade in his own image, friends and associates said he is standing by his pledge not to critique other presidents and political leaders.
"The job of the president is very hard to begin with," Ari Fleischer, former White House press secretary for Bush, told USA TODAY. "He doesn't want to make it harder for anyone, friend or foe."
"It's very old school," Fleischer added. "It's very gracious. It's very Bush."
It also has public benefits for the former president - his approval ratings have more than doubled since he left office more than 15 years ago.


Not my DV, but interestingly enough while Reagan might not be alive and some have drawn some parallels between Reagan and Trump, Trump managed to have a spat with Reagan's... library https://www.politico.com/news/magazine/2023/09/22/ronald-reagan-library-donald-trump-feud-00116983 GOP opposition to Trump has apparently found a niche with the Ronald Reagan Presidential Foundation and Institute, which runs the library.

To answer this question, we need to enumerate the people who served as presidents of the United States and enumerate the candidates endorsed by those presidents when Donald Trump himself was a candidate between 2016 and 2024.

Jimmy Carter: endorsed Hillary Clinton in 2016 and Joe Biden in 2020
Bill Clinton: Endorsed Hillary Clinton in 2016, Joe Biden in 2020
George H.W. Bush: did not vote for Donald Trump; said to have voted for Hillary.
George W. Bush: did not endorse any candidate in 2016 or 2020.
Barack Obama: Endorsed Hillary Clinton in 2016, Joe Biden in 2020

None of the above endorsed Donald Trump for President this year.
So the answer is, No, no U.S. president endorsed Donald Trump for U.S. presidency.

W. Bush claims to have cast a blank ballot [in 2016] according to one of the sources in Machavity's answer.
